# В каком порядке учить стек технологий под web?

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите, пожалуйста, вот я хочу научиться программировать под web (например написать сайт) на C#, знаю C# и немного html и сейчас немного в растерянности за что браться и в каком порядке: толи ASP.NET MVC, толи JavaScript, толи jquery, толи CSS учить, толи html подтягивать. Сразу все выучить как то уж слишком.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы уже знаете C#, то дальше рекомендую взяться за любой большой учебник или туториал по ASP.NET MVC (http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started например). На готовых примерах станет более понятно, что из себя представляет html/css/js, и что изучать далее.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы вздумали заняться именно ASP.NET MVC, то учить вам придется все вышеперечисленное. В первую очередь, конечно сам ASP.NET MVC, а уже во вторую - все прочее из вышеуказанного. Впрочем, могу обрадовать - в этом случае нет  необходимости знать CSS, JS и jQuery на очень высоком уровне уровне, а знакомство с HTML вряд ли отнимет у вас больше одного-двух дней. Более того, вполне может так случиться, что зная jQuery, вы редко будете испытывать потребность в чистом JS. Ну а CSS хоть и является для программиста полезной вещью, однако же и к самым необходимым скиллам его знание вряд ли отнесешь

Answer (score 0):

Когда я училась, то сначала все таки выдавали основы(повторяю основы, не нужно лезть во все нюансы, если не собираешься дальше только на этом писать) html, jQuery, css. А потом уже приступали к asp.net mvc, потому что там уже это все нужно использовать.

Comment: Где вы учились? :)